# How can I craft a generic BulkUpsertAsync method for MongoDB in C#?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am trying to build an extension method for `IMongoCollection<TDocument>` in C# which will allow any `List<TDocument>` to be upserted into a MongoDB collection using an upsert. I have found other articles that suggest a `List<WriteModel<TDocument>>`, in combination with BulkWriteAsync to perform these operations in a batch.

In a non-generic manner, I can upsert a series of entries (in this case a `List<Line>`) using:

```
public static async Task<BulkWriteResult<Line>> BulkUpsertAsyncNonGeneric(this IMongoCollection<Line> collection, List<Line> entries)
        {
            var bulkOps = new List<WriteModel<Line>>();

            foreach (var entry in entries)
            {
                var filter = Builders<Line>.Filter.Eq(doc => doc.Id, entry.Id);

                var upsertOne = new ReplaceOneModel<Line>(filter, entry) { IsUpsert = true };

                bulkOps.Add(upsertOne);
            }

            return await collection.BulkWriteAsync(bulkOps);
        }
```

By changing `<Line>` for `<TDocument>` I have made this partly generic, but there is an assumption that every TDocument has an `Id` field and that every `entry in entries` also has an `Id` field. Of course, `TDocument` has no members. I want to make these field definitions fully generic, ideally using a lambda to match the format of the call to `Filter.Eq(doc => doc.Id, entry.Id)`. However, I'm stuck. I *really* want to avoid simply passing a string literal with the field names, which I believe would work fine but isn't compile-time safe.

I've come up with the following, which unsurprisingly does not compile:

```
public static async Task<BulkWriteResult<TDocument>> BulkUpsertAsync<TDocument, TField>(this IMongoCollection<TDocument> collection, List<TDocument> entries, Expression<Func<TDocument, TField>> filterField, Expression<Func<TDocument, TField>> valueField)
    {
        var bulkOps = new List<WriteModel<TDocument>>();

        foreach (var entry in entries)
        {
            var filter = Builders<TDocument>.Filter.Eq(filterField, valueField);

            var upsertOne = new ReplaceOneModel<TDocument>(filter, entry) { IsUpsert = true };

            bulkOps.Add(upsertOne);
        }

        return await collection.BulkWriteAsync(bulkOps);
    }
```

I suspect the type of valueField is incorrect, but additionally the compiler complains that

> Error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from
>   `'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TDocument, TField>>'`
>   to `'MongoDB.Driver.FieldDefinition<TDocument,
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TDocument, TField>>>'`
>   (21, 48)

Comment: @dcg Unfortunately the change from code to quote has caused some rendering issues involving angle brackets!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get this working using a compiled lambda.

```
public static async Task<BulkWriteResult<TDocument>> BulkUpsertAsync<TDocument, TField>(
        this IMongoCollection<TDocument> collection,
        List<TDocument> entries,
        Expression<Func<TDocument, TField>> filterField)
    {
        var bulkOps = new List<WriteModel<TDocument>>();
        foreach (var entry in entries)
        {
            var filterFieldValue = filterField.Compile();
            var filter = Builders<TDocument>.Filter.Eq(filterField, filterFieldValue(entry));
            var upsertOne = new ReplaceOneModel<TDocument>(filter, entry) { IsUpsert = true };

            bulkOps.Add(upsertOne);
        }

        return await collection.BulkWriteAsync(bulkOps);
    }
```

The `Expression<Func<TDocument, TField>>` in the method signature lets me point at a property or field on `TDocument`, which is used in both the creation of the filter for MongoDB, as well as the in the iterator that creates the `ReplaceOneModel` for each `entry in entries`.

It can be called as follows:

```
// Given some List<T> of entries to upsert...
List<SomePoco> SomePocos = GetListOfPocoFromSomewhere();
// This will match existing documents on a field called "Name".
await SomeMongoCollection.BulkUpsertAsync(SomePocos, filterField => filterField.Name);
```

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: good stuff... thanks for sharing... btw, have you benchmarked the performance penalty of compiling expressions like this inside a loop?

Comment: An interesting point - I see no reason why the expression must be compiled in each iteration. I’ll look at moving the compilation to run once before the loop, and see if I can benchmark both approaches! Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to apply a generic constraint to your T. It still relies on having the item(s) of your interface (so id or whatever) but you can make that a very slim interface that you know **most** of your classes will be able to implement. And you get compile type safety.

We are not using extensions methods but have a wrapper nuget package that we use to access mongo via C#/Core 2.1

We have a specific interface IMongoDocument which we can then use to define our filters etc

```
public async Task UpdateAsync<T>(T entity) where T : IMongoDocument
{
    string originalDocumentVersion = entity.DocumentVersion;
    var filter = Builders<T>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Id, entity.Id);

    entity.DocumentVersion = ObjectId.GenerateNewId().ToString();

    ReplaceOneResult result = await this.Collection<T>().ReplaceOneAsync(this.session, filter, entity).ConfigureAwait(false);

    CheckResult(result.IsAcknowledged, result.IsAcknowledged ? result.ModifiedCount : 0);
}

public interface IMongoDocument : IDocumentIdentifier, IDocumentVersion
{     
}

public interface IDocumentIdentifier
{
    string Id { get; set; }
}

public interface IDocumentVersion
{
    string DocumentVersion { get; set; }
}
```

> this.session is being used because we are using mongo transactions and can
>   be ignore if you are not!

This example shows an update but passing in a list of IMongoDocuments (or whatever your interface might end up being) to a method with a generic constraint should allow you to be generic (to a point) for your bulk update. The key point seems to be building the filter correctly.

If you don't want to adhere to an interface the only other way I can think of is to dig into your class(es) via reflection to generate the filter but I would suggest that as a last resort!

Comment: I had a look at using a marker interface but unfortunately the objects I'm storing in Mongo aren't all mine and I can't add the interface to them without a new derived type.

I did have success with lambdas and (maybe) reflection. Example will be posted below in a few seconds...

Comment: Cool, glad you found a solution